# Apache access log : Property to map the logs of mutiple http requests of single webpage

Tags: http, web, http-headers, apache2, webbrowser-control

which property will be need to configure in Apache Log Format String,to map the multiple web requests of single web page..
For Example, We request www.google.com webpage in browser,it subrequest necessary images,javascript file while rendering.In apache each request was logged.. how to filter the subrequest logs www.google.com web page.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to add two new variables to your configured logformat.

- load mod_usertrack which assigns an identifier to each visitor via a cookie.  Log the cookie with You can then log it by appending a new variable to whatever `LogFormat` you currently use: %{cookie-name}C
- add %{Referer}i which is the referring web page.

Comment: its providing session id for each user. then its be group by session based logs